# Httpd can't access file even after setting httpd_sys_content_t

Tags: centos, fedora, selinux

I'm currently learning SELinux. I was following the instructions in [SELinux doc of RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server-Configuration_examples.html). I indeed succeded after typing the following commands:

```
mkdir /mywebsite  
//add something to /mywebsite/index.html  
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/mywebsite(/.*)?"  
restorecon -R -v /mywebsite //everythins worked well by then
```

But I did something more afterwards:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /mywebsite  //I can't access index.html now, as expected

restorecon -R -v /mywebsite //Still can't access index.html!!  

semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/mywebsite(/.*)?"  
restorecon -R -v /mywebsite  //didn't work, either

ls -dZ /mywebsite // unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
```

The error message in firefox is:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.
```

Am I missing something? Or it is a bug? My OS is Fedora 20 with Apache 2.4.7.

Comment: Just a stupid question. How are the permissions to the index.html file?

Comment: @ludiegu It's -rw-r--r--. No problem.

Comment: @I have solved it. Not a SELinux problem, but a httpd configuration problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake. This is not SELinux's fault. The tutorial on red hat is not complete. We should also add the following to the httpd configuration file(for apache httpd 2.4):

```
<Directory "/mywebsite">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can clone the configuration from the directory `/var/www/html`:

```
chcon -R --reference=/var/www/html /path/to/your/project
```